# Pogrammatically Change The Database Location

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, visual-studio

Im making a program with visual basic 2010 and using sqlserver compact as database. I have two folders named "Year2015" and "Year2016". The folders are in the same location where the program is. Both folders has a database named "MyData.sdf" in themselves. Both of the "MyData.sdf" has the same tables etc. Im trying to do something like that: 
When user select "Year2015", program starts to run with the data of "MyData.sdf" that is in the folder "Year2015" and when user select "Year2016", program starts to run with the data of "MyData.sdf" that is in the folder "Year2016". I mean that i want to change the datasource address programmaticly. Searched net for that. There are some explanations but no codes i could find. If this is a bad question sorry for that.

Comment: i used sqlserver compact. Im not good at databases. Program doesnt work online. Just getting data from sdf file.

Comment: You can use two connection string in app.config / web.config file and used that two connection string based on selection of dropdown Year2015 / Year2016 for getting data from different folder database like if else statement...

Comment: I can manage when user change the dropdown menu and select Year2015 with if else statement. But i dont know how do i make the program to start to work the databese in the folder Year 2015. I mean some codes like that: myconnection.source=CurrentDir & "Year2015/MyData.sdf" to change the database location if possible.

Comment: one thing you can do is define two variables in app.config / web.config in which one contains Year2015 path & second is Year2016 path so default you can set what ever you want to like and also you can change the connection string by using StringFormat("connectionstringPath={0}", pathVariable);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally create my own code for this issue. I want to share it for the people who uses VB2010 and SQL Server Compact and want to change the data source for the active form. The code is:

```
Dim sConnectionString As String
sConnectionString = "Data Source=" & My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Year2015\MyData.sdf"
TableAdapterManager.Connection.ConnectionString = sConnectionString
```

This will change your data source of active form. The other forms continues to use the default source

Answer (score 1):

Dave Pinal is a genius at this stuff, and I happened to read his blog on this very topic:

`ALTER DATABASE TestDB
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO`

-- Detach DB

`EXEC MASTER.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'TestDB'
GO`

-- Move MDF File from Loc1 to Loc 2
-- Re-Attached DB

`CREATE DATABASE [TestDB] ON
( FILENAME = N'F:\loc2\TestDB.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'F:\loc2\TestDB_log.ldf' )
FOR ATTACH
GO`

Note: even his comment sections are great, too!

*SOURCE SCRIPT CAME FROM PINAL.
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/10/28/sql-server-move-database-files-mdf-and-ldf-to-another-location/

Comment: Thanks. Dave Pinal has explained clearly what i want. But in another programming language. Triying to change the codes to vb2010 express. But everytime some errors.

Comment: I mean when i write the code of Dave Pinal, but visual basic underlines the codes because its not written in visual basic language. Im trying to change it to vb2010 lang. If i could do, it will be so nice...

Comment: Ah. Then in that case, this link might work: A guy moved a localdb in VB 2010. You can perhaps take how he wrote the code to work?
[link](https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=2636)

Comment: Perhaps instead of moving database from folder "Year2016" to "Year2015" we can make our program to change the database source from folder "Year2015" to folder "Year2016". Thanks for your helps.

Comment: No problem. I learn more things, and you get closer to an acceptable alternative. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114686/discussion-between-clifton-h-and-user747699).